# Why does the following code compile but not run?

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

```
class Demo
{
    Demo()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello From Demo");
    }
}

class demo
{   
    demo()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello From Small Demo");
    }
}

class Test
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        Demo d1=new Demo();
        demo d2=new demo();
    }
}
```

This code compiles but not doesn't run; When I try to run this program, it gives a `classNotFoundException`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: How are you trying to run the code?  From the command line or an ide?

Comment: Are these classes all defined in the same file? How did you run the program?

Comment: Go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890805/case-sensitivity-of-java-class-names) post it might help you.

Comment: @mluisbrown Not a strict duplicate, but explains why it can fail on some systems. Good find

Answer (score 12):

Under Unix, and/or compiled into a .jar application, file names are case case-sensitive. And all would work: demo.class, Demo.class.

Under Windows the compilation of demo and Demo will overwrite one file.