# Could not find main class in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

```
package abc ;   
class Trying
{
Trying ()
{
    System.out.println("hello");
}
        }

public class trying {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Trying () ;
}

}
```

In this when I change the name of class from Trying to some other name it works , but here it says :

Error: Could not find or load main class abc.trying
/Users/name/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Why is this happening ?
I didn't find such case in any of the questions already asked .

Comment: Which jdk and OS you are using?

Comment: I have installed this : jdk-8u121-macosx-x64 (1).dmg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is case sensitive language, but there is no documentation that class name should be case sensitive or not.

In eclipse it will show you syntax error

> Class file collision: A resource exists with a different case:
>   '/sample/bin/abc/Trying.class'.

OR

If not shows error it will create class file of only one class either `Trying` or `trying`.

**1)**
If class file of `Trying` class is generated then It will throw

> Error: Main method not found in class abc.trying

Since there is no main method in class `Trying`, And at runtime it looking for main method to start.

**2)**
If class file of `trying` class is generated then It will throw

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

here at runtime it looking for class `Trying` since it called in `main` of class `trying`. It fails to load coz its not compiled.

So we can conclude java not allow two class with sameName even different case

more details of case sensitive of class name is  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890805/case-sensitivity-of-java-class-names)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Trying
{
    Trying ()
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}

public class Try_Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Trying () ;
    }
}
```

Please use two different class names other than same name with different cases. **On compilation, the compilation will success and compile will create two class files with same name but different cases. But, the OS only allows a single file and it simply overwrites first one( which created firstly on compilation, then second) by the second one.** On running, you will get a run time error, because one of the classes is missing. So, please use different names...

Answer (score 0):

Well, this class should be **public** **and be sure of saving the file name as the class Name**

Answer (score -1):

You have specified Trying multiple times.

```
package abc;

public class Trying {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        trying1();

    }

    public static void trying1() {

        System.out.println("Good?!");

    }

}
```

Comment: Class names are case sensitive though, are they not? `Trying` and `trying` are two different classes, no?

Comment: trying and Trying are different classes.